# Run Ansible Playbooks by region

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

first of all: I am still an Ansible newbie and I am just getting used to it.

i want to write a playbook that calls up a different playbook depending on the location of the client.

For example: 
i have 3 different playbooks specifically for certain regions, usaclient.yml, euclient.yml and asiaclient.yml

these playbooks should be executed automatically via a "master playbook".

if the "master playbook" is executed on a european client, the playbook "euclient.yml" should be started.

does anyone know how to assign playbooks automatically to a region or has an idea how to solve this by bash script?

best regards 
D1Ck3n

Comment: Hi @D1Ck3n, Welcome to SOF!
It would be good, if the questions has the below aspects for getting better answers,
1. Objective you're trying to achieve
2. Issue or error details or code samples
3. Research effort from your end to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"If the "master playbook" is executed on a European client, the playbook `euclient.yml` should be started."*

A: In Ansible it's not possible to start a playbook conditionally. See [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook).

There are 2 options only. Start the playbook conditionally by an external tool or test the condition inside the playbook. Try [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone.html).