# How to run Ansible playbook conditionally?

Tags: ansible

how do i run some playbooks based on condition. I will explain my current scenario -
I have a main yml - `main.yml` which is importing 4 playbooks with conditions as below -

```
---
- import_playbook: current-deployment-status.yml

- import_playbook: current-config-status.yml

- import_playbook: full-deployment.yml
  when: target_release_version != current_release

- import_playbook: only-config-change.yml
  #when: config_var.changed  == true and target_release_version == current_release
```

The 1st playbook `current-deployment-status.yml` gets the current release version deployed and register a variable `current_release`.
Likewise the 2nd playbook do some configuration checks and registers into a variable `config_var`.

Now based on these 2 variables, I have to execute my further playbooks. If `target_release_version == current_release` then I don't want to do the deployment so only execute `full-deployment.yml` when condition meets as above.

Likewise, if there is only configuration change required and no deployment : `config_var.changed  == true and target_release_version == current_release`, then execute `only-config-change.yml`

Is there a way to execute the playbook only when condition meets otherwise skip it and proceed further.

Please let me know if someone can guide me in the right direction

Comment: It's not possible. Import_playbook isn't a task. It's [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592342/run-ansible-playbooks-by-region/61593138#61593138). I voted to close it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Ansible Playbooks by region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592342/run-ansible-playbooks-by-region)

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks Vlad for the response. I looked into the link but that does not solve my problem. Could you suggest some other way through which I could achieve this. **Basically the thing is in my scenario there could be 2 cases, one is full deployment which includes code + config and another is just config. In the just config case I just want to restart tomcat and exit the play and do nothing else. And in case of full deployment my plaobook does multiple things like,  downloading and copying the release to remote host, creating new symlinks, stop/start tomcat etc.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve it using set_facts Ansible module.

**main.yml**

```yaml
---
- import_playbook: current-deployment-status.yml

- import_playbook: current-config-status.yml

- import_playbook: full-deployment.yml
  when: target_release_version != current_release

- import_playbook: only-config-change.yml
  when: config_var.changed  == true and target_release_version == current_release
```

**current-deployment-status.yml**

```yaml
- name : Playbook current-deployment-status
  hosts: all 
  user: ubuntu 
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: echo playbook name 
      shell: echo "current-deployment-status.yml"

    - set_fact:
        current_release: "2"
```

**current-config-status.yml**

```yaml
- name : Playbook current-config-status.yml
  hosts: all 
  user: ubuntu 
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: echo playbook name 
      shell: echo "current-config-status.yml"

    - name: task2
      shell: echo "another task"
      register: config_var

    - debug: msg="{{config_var.changed}}"
```

**full-deployment.yml**

```yaml
- name : Playbook
  hosts: all 
  user: ubuntu 
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: echo playbook name 
      shell: echo "full_deployment.yml"
```

**only-config-change.yml**

```yaml
- name : Playbook only-config-change.yml
  hosts: all 
  user: ubuntu 
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - name: echo playbook name 
      shell: echo "only-config-change.yml"
```

`ansible-playbook -i 172.31.6.248, main.yml -v --extra-vars "target_release_version=2"`

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-43:~/ansible_test$ ansible-playbook -i 172.31.6.248, main.yml -v --extra-vars "target_release_version=2"
PLAY [Playbook current-deployment-status] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248]

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"current-deployment-status.yml\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002429", "end": "2020-05-31 16:46:29.900240", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:46:29.897811", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "current-deployment-status.yml", "stdout_lines": ["current-deployment-status.yml"]}

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248] => {"ansible_facts": {"current_release": "2"}, "changed": false}

PLAY [Playbook current-config-status.yml] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248]

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"current-config-status.yml\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002484", "end": "2020-05-31 16:46:30.776486", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:46:30.774002", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "current-config-status.yml", "stdout_lines": ["current-config-status.yml"]}

TASK [task2] ****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"another task\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002473", "end": "2020-05-31 16:46:31.048677", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:46:31.046204", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "another task", "stdout_lines": ["another task"]}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248] => {
    "msg": true
}

PLAY [Playbook full_deployment.yml] *****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

PLAY [Playbook only-config-change.yml] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248]

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"only-config-change.yml\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002585", "end": "2020-05-31 16:46:32.017156", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:46:32.014571", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "only-config-change.yml", "stdout_lines": ["only-config-change.yml"]}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
172.31.6.248               : ok=9    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

`ansible-playbook -i 172.31.6.248, main.yml -v --extra-vars "target_release_version=3"`

```
PLAY [Playbook current-deployment-status] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248]

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"current-deployment-status.yml\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002490", "end": "2020-05-31 16:48:28.611482", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:48:28.608992", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "current-deployment-status.yml", "stdout_lines": ["current-deployment-status.yml"]}

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248] => {"ansible_facts": {"current_release": "2"}, "changed": false}

PLAY [Playbook current-config-status.yml] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248]

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"current-config-status.yml\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002565", "end": "2020-05-31 16:48:29.440319", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:48:29.437754", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "current-config-status.yml", "stdout_lines": ["current-config-status.yml"]}

TASK [task2] ****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"another task\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002459", "end": "2020-05-31 16:48:29.703006", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:48:29.700547", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "another task", "stdout_lines": ["another task"]}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248] => {
    "msg": true
}

PLAY [Playbook full_deployment.yml] *****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.31.6.248]

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"full_deployment.yml\"", "delta": "0:00:00.002509", "end": "2020-05-31 16:48:30.610648", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-05-31 16:48:30.608139", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "full_deployment.yml", "stdout_lines": ["full_deployment.yml"]}

PLAY [Playbook only-config-change.yml] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

TASK [echo playbook name] ***************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
172.31.6.248               : ok=9    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response mate but in your output I could see the playbook has been skipped ```PLAY [Playbook full_deployment.yml] *****************************************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************
skipping: [172.31.6.248] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}``` But in my playbook I couldn't find anything like this. Although the tasks are not getting executed but everything related to that playbook is getting printed

Comment: Also as Vladimir mentioned we can't out conditions in import-playbook as it's not a task so not sure the when statement is valid or not

Comment: That is an expected behaviour of when command. Even though the task are skipped it will be printed in the output as skipped. I don't understand what else you need.